# Match and substitute whole visual range in vim

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I wanted to visually mark a few lines and then surround the whole range with <p> and </p>. After a lot of fiddling I have come up with this substitute command that seams to work:

`:'<,'>s/^\(\_.*\)\%V/<p>\1<\/p>/`

Is there a better way of doing this or could someone explain why it works?

`\_.` matches every characters including end-of-line. The `^` (start-of-line) and the `\%V` (match visual range) seams to behave strange. For example the documentation suggest that you use two `\%V` to surround your expression but that does not seams to be necessary. Using no `\%V` or having only one at the start matches the whole buffer. Removing the `^` causes the last line to be matched and substituted separately. A `$` at the end seams to be unnecessary also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Use surround vim

You can use [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697), in visual mode:

<kbd>`s<p`</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

E.g. `vat` (visual select 'around' tag), `s<p` surround with `<p>...</p>`

Breakdown:

- vat (visually select a tag; do any visual selection you wanted)
- s< (surround with tag), in this case, `p`

#### 2. Use ex commands with the range markers

**Edit**: without surround you would be able to either

> <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>'<</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>**`<p>`**<kbd>Esc</kbd>
>
> <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>'></kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>**`</p>`**<kbd>Esc</kbd>

#### 3. Use yank and XML filetype plugin inserting register contents:

Or much simpler:

> <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>**`<p>`<sup>1</sup>**<kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Note that at **<sup>1</sup>** my XML filtetype plugin (I think it is default) automatically provided the closing tag (`</p>`) so we can just insert the *yanked* contents using <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> --- without even leaving insert mode!

Comment: Added non-surround alternatives too: IMO it is always best to know the vim-like approach before extending using plugins. That way, you can do things that plugins don't do for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was about to convert a text document with titles and paragraphs to HTML. surround.vim seams to work quite nice. Only two issues, first I got `surround.vim: Visual mode s has been removed in favor of S` so I used `S` instead. Secondly, is there a way to not insert new lines before and after and not indent as `S` does?

Comment: @MattiasWadman: I think `:he vgS` should give you what you need